# MySQL Replace string SUM then total

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sum, union

Looking to get a total for each ID from the sum of the replacement fields.

```
SELECT
    insurance_carrier as ID, SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','')) AS es_reserve,
    SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-',''))AS structure_reserve,
    SUM(es_reserve+structure_reserve) AS total
FROM job_tbl
WHERE
    job_status NOT IN(2,4,6,7,9) AND
    insurance_carrier !=0 AND      
    FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%m') = MONTH(NOW()) AND
    FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%Y') = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY insurance_carrier
```

I get the results from es_reserve and structure_reserve but the total is 0.

BTW the fields contain items like $2,300- that's the reason for the replace

Any help would be appreciated!!!

EDIT: here is the results this produces

```
Array
(
[ID] => 14
[es_reserve] => 5000
[structure_reserve] => 35000
)

Array
(
[ID] => 15
[es_reserve] => 2500
[structure_reserve] => 2500
)

Array
(
[ID] => 41
[es_reserve] => 2500
[structure_reserve] => 2500
)

Array
(
[ID] => 44
[es_reserve] => 2500
[structure_reserve] => 
)
```

Here is what I would like it to produce

```
Array
(
[ID] => 14
[es_reserve] => 5000
[structure_reserve] => 35000
[total] => 40000
)

Array
(
[ID] => 15
[es_reserve] => 2500
[structure_reserve] => 2500
[total] => 5000
)

Array
(
[ID] => 41
[es_reserve] => 2500
[structure_reserve] => 2500
[total] => 5000
)

Array
(
[ID] => 44
[es_reserve] => 2500
[structure_reserve] => 
[total] => 2500
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Total column is doing sum on original column value , the alias name defined in the select won't be used in the same select.
You can repeat replace statement while doing total column computation

```
SUM(  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','') 
      + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-',''))
Total,
```

instead of

```
SUM(es_reserve+structure_reserve) as total
```

The query becomes, with order by as asked in comment.

```
SELECT insurance_carrier as ID, SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','')) AS es_reserve, SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-',''))AS structure_reserve, SUM( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','') + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','')) as Total FROM job_tbl WHERE job_status NOT IN(2,4,6,7,9) AND insurance_carrier !=0 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%m') = MONTH(NOW()) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%Y') = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY insurance_carrier
order by SUM( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','') + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','')) desc
```

OR
use it as subquery

```
SELECT T.*,     SUM(es_reserve+structure_reserve) AS total
FROM 
(

SELECT
    insurance_carrier as ID, SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','')) AS es_reserve,
    SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-',''))AS structure_reserve

FROM job_tbl
WHERE
    job_status NOT IN(2,4,6,7,9) AND
    insurance_carrier !=0 AND      
    FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%m') = MONTH(NOW()) AND
    FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%Y') = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY insurance_carrier
) T
```

Comment: What can we do to avoid that repetition and allow a more readable query?

Comment: the first result gives the total only and the other sums are missing. Second result gives total for each sum but doesn't gives sums by ID. So i need a sum for each ID for the reserves and a total of all those sums by ID. Here is what that might look like,
[0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 14
            [es_reserve] => 5000
            [structure_reserve] => 35000
            [total] => 50000
        )
[0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 151
            [es_reserve] => 5000
            [structure_reserve] => 5000
            [total] => 10000
        )

Comment: @user2823774, just replace total with my statement, keep remaining as your statement so you get every thing

Comment: here is what im using:
SELECT T.*,  SUM(es_reserve+structure_reserve) AS total
FROM 
(

SELECT
    insurance_carrier as ID, SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','')) AS es_reserve,
    SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-',''))AS structure_reserve

FROM job_tbl
WHERE
    job_status NOT IN(2,4,6,7,9) AND
    insurance_carrier !=0 AND      
    FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%m') = MONTH(NOW()) AND
    FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%Y') = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY insurance_carrier
) T

Comment: and here is the result: Array
(
    [ID] => 14
    [es_reserve] => 5000
    [structure_reserve] => 35000
    [total] => 50000
)

There should be 4 results

Comment: Does your original qury giving 4 results, i suspect it to give only 1 row,

Comment: here is result without total 
Array
(
    [ID] => 14
    [es_reserve] => 5000
    [structure_reserve] => 35000
)

Array
(
    [ID] => 15
    [es_reserve] => 2500
    [structure_reserve] => 2500
)

Array
(
    [ID] => 41
    [es_reserve] => 2500
    [structure_reserve] => 2500
)

Array
(
    [ID] => 44
    [es_reserve] => 2500
    [structure_reserve] => 
)

Comment: try this, SELECT
    insurance_carrier as ID, SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','')) AS es_reserve,
    SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-',''))AS structure_reserve,
SUM(  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(es_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-','') 
      + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(structure_reserve,'$',''),',',''),'-',''))
as Total, 
FROM job_tbl
WHERE
    job_status NOT IN(2,4,6,7,9) AND
    insurance_carrier !=0 AND      
    FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%m') = MONTH(NOW()) AND
    FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_loss,'%Y') = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY insurance_carrier

Comment: Awesome! That worked...just change Total, FROM to Total FROM. One thing I forgot is I need the the highest total to show first. Is that possible?  Can you update your response?

Comment: Yes , you can add order by Total desc at the end, if it is helpful , you can accept the answer